# PHP - Regex, remove font tag

Tags: php, regex

Could someone tell me why this isn't working please?

```
$str = preg_replace("<font[^>]*>", '', $str);
```

CMS is for flash and now the client wants to implement a html website. Need to remove evil inline font tags to show default styling.

Comment: Consider using a XML/SGML parser instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use preg_replace have a look on this function 
(in this link you will found a lot of function to do this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Here is support for stripping content for the reverse strip_tags function:

```
<?php
function strip_only($str, $tags, $stripContent = false) {
    $content = '';
    if(!is_array($tags)) {
        $tags = (strpos($str, '>') !== false ? explode('>', str_replace('<', '', $tags)) : array($tags));
        if(end($tags) == '') array_pop($tags);
    }
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        if ($stripContent)
             $content = '(.+</'.$tag.'[^>]*>|)';
         $str = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>'.$content.'#is', '', $str);
    }
    return $str;
}

$str = '<font color="red">red</font> text';
$tags = 'font';
$a = strip_only($str, $tags); // red text
$b = strip_only($str, $tags, true); // text
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, answer then is. $str = preg_replace("#<font[^>]*>#is", '', $str);

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this one.

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<font[^>]*>)|(<\/font>)/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any delimiters on your pattern. This should work:

```
$str = preg_replace('/<font[^>]*>/', '', $str);
```

Obligatory "don't use regular expressions to parse HTML".

Comment: I am not really using regex to parse HTML. The Flash text editor throws out invalid garbage. Just need to remove the one tag with inline styles until I get someone in to create a vanilla text editor that can create both Flash + W3C valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
#<font[^>]*>#
```

How isn't the delimiter there? The delimiter is #.

> #### "A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character." [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)